# Search functionality logic is not working properly

Tags: swift4, swift5

Here is my single line Search functionality code which is not filtering results properly. Can anyone let me know what I have to change in the code to display the array elements I am searching with first three characters of text.

For the first character I entered it is showing results. But entering second and third elements it is not showing any results

Search Functionality Logic:

```
searchFruit = data.filter{$0.range(of: textSearched, options: [.caseInsensitive, .anchored]) != nil}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

var data = ["apple","bananna","dragon fruit", "mango","pineapple"]
var searchFruit = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchFruit = data
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return searchFruit.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
    cell?.textLabel?.text = searchFruit[indexPath.row]
    return cell!
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    searchFruit = (searchText.isEmpty) ? self.data : self.data.filter({ (searchValue) -> Bool in
        return searchValue.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
    })
    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

}